# Communication between PhoneGap, usb external device and Android host mode

Tags: android, cordova, usb, external-accessory

I need to communicate with an external device with PhoneGap on Android.

It is working by bluetooth with a PhoneGap plugin. Now I want to communicate by the USB port.

Is is possible with PhoneGap, to have access to an external device, by using the USB host capabilities of an Android device?

Any existing PhoneGap / Cordova plugins?

Any examples?

I'm having a hard time finding something similar to prove my concept...

Answer (score 7):

I have developed such plugin, see https://github.com/xseignard/cordovarduino

Maybe it will fit your needs

Comment: Invoking "serial.requestPermission" returns updates the error: "No device found!".

How do I recognize my device?

Comment: Hello,
Please provide more detailled information about your issue here: https://github.com/xseignard/cordovarduino/issues

Answer (score 0):

I think you'll have to write your own Cordova plugin that uses USB Host api: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/usb/host.html  I couldn't find any preexisting plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Use [cordova-plugin-usb-event](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-usb-event) to list all connected devices's PID & VID

```
cordova.plugins.usbevent.listDevices(
      function(list) {
        console.log(list);
      },
      function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      });
```

And write and receive data via [cordovarduino](https://github.com/xseignard/cordovarduino)

```
var errorCallback = function(message) {
    alert('Error: ' + message);
};

serial.requestPermission({
    vid: '1d50',
    pid: '607d',
    driver: 'FtdiSerialDriver' // or any other
},
    function(successMessage) {
        serial.open(
            {baudRate: 9600},
            function(successMessage) {
                serial.write(
                    '1',
                    function(successMessage) {
                        alert(successMessage);
                    },
                    errorCallback
                );
            },
            errorCallback
        );
    },
    errorCallback
);
```